# How can I chain RxJS observable in a redux-observable epic?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I've just started learning redux-observables and RxJS for work recently. We have alerts globally set in Redux.  I want to be able to set an alert, then after a set period, close that same alert. There can also be multiple alerts at any time, and the user could manually close one alert before it automatically closes itself. I have added to id here, so I can close the correct alert.
I have attempted to use delay after the initial map than another map to achieve this so far. However, this skips the first map.

```
export const addAlertEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = (
  action$,
  state$
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(slice.actions.addAlert),
    map((values: any) =>
      slice.actions.addAlertSuccess({ id: uuid(), ...values.payload })
    )
  );
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> set an alert, then after a set period, close that same alert [...] he user could manually close one alert before it automatically closes itself

With that in mind, here would be my approach:

```js
actions$.pipe(
  ofType(slice.actions.addAlert),

  // `There can also be multiple alerts at any time`
  mergeMap(action => {
    const id = uuid();

    // using `NEVER` is important, it's essentially the same as new Observable(() => {})
    // it is needed because we don't want the inner observable to complete unless `takeUntil` decides to
    return NEVER
      .pipe(

        // start with opening the alert
        startWith(slice.actions.addAlertSuccess({ id, ...action.payload }))
        
        // close the alert either
        takeUntil(merge(
          
          // when `TIME` expires
          timer(TIME),
          
          // or when the user decides to
          userClosedActions.pipe(
            filter(action => action.id === id)
          )
        )),

        // at the end(when the stream completed due to `takeUntil`), close the alert
        endWith(slice.actions.closeAlertSuccess(...))
      )
  })
)
```

`userClosedActions` can be a `Subject` that sends `next` notifications as a result of user action. For example:

```js
onClick (closedId) {
 userClosedActions.next({ id: closedId })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the detailed answer. How do I create a subject and tie that into my epic? Or could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ChyMeng I’m not sure what the best approach is in this case(in Angular it would be dependency injection), but I’d create the subject in the same file where the epic resides and then you could import it in your components

Answer (score 0):

Add another epic for addAlertSucess, include a delay to dispatch the remove action.

```
export const addAlertSuccessEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = (
  action$,
  state$
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(slice.actions.addAlertSuccess),
    delay(myTimeToWait),
    map(foo =>
      slice.actions.removeAlert({ id: foo.id })
    )
  );
```